# Set date with WMIC (Invalid Verb Switch)

Tags: date, batch-file, wmic

I have revised my question do to comments below pointing me in new directions. I tried date.exe but it fails to set the command in all instances, even with it's returned timestamp.

So I moved on to WMIC. However, I also cannot seem to set the date. But I believe it may be my understanding of WMIC. Can anyone spot any errors in my approach?

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "trail=%dt:~8%" & set "backdt=%dt:~0,8%"
set "targetstamp=20150419%trail%"
echo %targetstamp%
targetstamp
wmic OS Set localdatetime=%targetstamp%
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "ndt=%%a"
set "newtrail=%ndt:~8%"
echo %backdt&&newtrail%
wmic OS Set localdatetime=%backdt%%newtrail%
pause
```

Comment: Why are you picking apart `%date%` when you save it? Why not just save `%date%` as-is? It should be in an appropriate format for the `date` command to accept subsequently.

Comment: I know that my `%date%` variable starts with the day of the week, which would set the `%BackupDate%` variable to `Wed 04/2`, which would absolutely break the `date` command. I have no way of testing this, but it's likely that Europeans also have the day of the week in their date variable.

Comment: With German date/time settings set in region and language settings the environment variable __DATE__ contains today the string `23.04.2015` and __TIME__ has `7:19:33,89` (starting with a space).

Comment: I recommend ISO-8601-format for international date/time-exchange, for example: 2015-04-23T13:43+01:00

Comment: That UnxUtils `date.exe` looks promising. Thanks for the replies!

Comment: Well UnxUtils `date.exe` doesn't seem to be able to set the date, even with it's raw timestamp and timestamp input. So I am tried WMIC. But I am having issues setting the date here too (lol)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so you get the current time, replace the date while keeping the time and TZ offset, set that datetime, then do some work right after the `wmic os set` command, and revert with the then current time.

Your code is correct. Note that in order to set the date/time via `wmic` you need to run the command with elevated privileges, like in Windows-Start-"cmd"-right click-"Run as Administrator".

**Edit:**
No, what you see is what `cmd.exe` leaves behind after treating the Unicode output of `wmic`. It needs some heavy string pulling to get rid of the extra '\r' in the output.
This now is running without errors on my PC:

```
    @echo off
    setlocal

    set dt=
    for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('wmic OS Get localDateTime /value ^| findstr "."') do @set dt=%%A
    set dt=%dt:~14,-1%
    set "trail=%dt:~8%"
    set "saveddt=%dt:~0,8%"
    set targetstamp=20150419%trail%
    wmic OS Set localdatetime=%targetstamp%

    REM do some work...
    pause

    set dt=
    for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('wmic OS Get localDateTime /value ^| findstr "."') do @set dt=%%A
    set dt=%dt:~14,-1%
    set "newtrail=%dt:~8%"
    wmic OS Set localdatetime=%saveddt%%newtrail%
```

Running in a privileged CMD it reports having set the new date. However, nothing changes on my PC - `wmic OS set localdatetime` just doesn't change the date. YMMV.

Comment: I had a random `"` interfering with the new stamp. However I get `invalid verb switch.` now, admin or not.

Comment: Hmm interesting. I'll have to come up with alternative to this whacky old app then.

Answer (score 1):

One of the offsets in your code is incorrect:

```
set BackupDate=%date:~0,6%%date:~10,2%
```

Now,

```
C:\>set bd=%date:~0,6%%date:~10,2% && echo %bd%
23.04.15
```

Comment: Thanks, in light of various region formats, and the customizability of the string, I am trying a new approach. See updated question.